# Как из функции вынести значение переменной которая была заданна через параметры?

Tags: javascript

```
var formSPStatusColor = 0;
var formSPStatusSize = 0;
var formSPStatusQuantity = 0;

function funFormSP(el, status) {
  if (status == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].style.transform = 'rotateX(0deg)';
    return status = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].style.transform = 'rotateX(90deg)';
    return status = 0;
  }

}
```

`<div onclick="funFormSP('selectedColorActive', formSPStatusColor)">Нажми</div>`

При нажати, передаётся класс элемента и статус нажатий (1й раз нажат или 2й). после срабатывания статус должен принимать значение "1". Он это и делает, но я не знаю как вынести его за пределы функции, что бы он присвоился переменной которая была указанна в параметрах

Answer (score 0):

Отлично! Если я вас правильно понял то вам всего то на всего нужно было глобально изменить значение переменой переданной в параметры. И я вас поздравлю! Это невозможно!
Мы можем попытаться сделать это немного иначе:

1. через объект:

   ```
   let varible = {
    value : undefined
   }
   function test(obj){
    obj.value = 0
   } 
   test(varible)
   ```

объекты как мы знаем это всего лишь набор ссылок на ячейки памяти и тут свойство `value` общее у объекта `varible` и `obj`.

2. с помощью `return`:

   ```
   let varible = 0;
   function test(value){
    return value
   }
   varible = test(varible)
   ```

и если вам нужно изменять значение переменой переданной в параметрах вы что-то делаете не так

Comment: Может тогда есть более простой способ создать выпадающее меню, внутри которого должен быть блочный элемент? Но таких элементов должно быть 3

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, который я не совсем понял. Ну типа вы можете загуглить

Comment: вообщем вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221456/Как-сделать-выпадающий-список-с-выбором-с-блочным-элементом-внутри.
Что то я понять не могу как это сделать