# Как сделать выпадающий список с выбором (с блочным элементом внутри)

Tags: javascript

[image: итоговый вариант]

Таких элементов на странице 3, при нажатии вниз должен выезжать список с элементами (так же цвет и название). Через select не получиться, так как он не принимает в себя блочные теги. Как это можно сделать? или делать под каждый список отдельную функцию на JS? При нажатии на элемент внутри списка, он должен отображаться выбранным

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать фреймворк `Bootstrap 4`. Вы рано или поздно к нему придёте, если ещё не пришли. Для выпадающего меню в Bootstrap есть класс `dropdown`.

Вот так это выглядит:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://google.com">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://google.com">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://google.com">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

А если вы по какой-то причине не хотите подключать никакие сторонние фреймворки, вы всегда можете посмотреть исходники `Bootstrap`, как это устроено там.

Comment: Почему человек придёт к бутстрапу? :) . Он далеко не везде нужен и многими не используется вообще, у него хватает недостатков.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я знаю. Я сам его не люблю и всячески избегаю. Но в условиях, когда вёрстка поставлена на поток, он доволен удобен и популярен. По-крайней мере я так думаю, а я не верстальщик и могу ошибаться.